# For chicken-and-egg apps which require a network effect, should I try to delay my user from noticing early on that there aren't many others?

Tags: usability, forms, user-behavior, user-expectation, registration

For example, in my user registration, I can let the user pick preferences for other users, similar to a dating app.

If those other users get filtered out, this introduces the possibility for the user's first impression using the app to be, "Oh, there's nobody here. Is this thing dead?" -> close -> uninstall -> and they'll probably never come back. Churn. Actually, it's just brand new!

So while I'm growing the app and there's not many on it yet, should I leave those preferences out of the registration, just so they'll see a bunch of people to begin with and their first impression isn't that the app is dead, and slightly delay it, allowing them to choose the preferences later? They could still potentially get value from the app even if it's not just their strict preferences right away.

I know there's not too much I can do here cause they'll find out eventually, but what is your recommendation?

Comment: More specific details about your app and use case would probably be helpful. For instance, is the app at all useful without many other users (such as a single player mode in games)? And how critical is it that users' preferences match?

Comment: It's not very useful without other users, so unlike a single player mode in games. User preferences matching is a really nice to have, but I'm not sure if at the cost of seeing few or no results as a 1st impression. It's like a LinkedIn. Say you're looking for Designers, specifically, Designers from X company. This preference in question has more to do with the specificity of "X company". It would be great if you got from X company, exactly what you're looking for, but you might discover a Designer from Y company instead, who fits your bill. There is still value in seeing Designers in general.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but in the case where they've filtered out too many people you should have a message/screen showing "You're limiting your potential reach, expand filters to see more" or something.

Answer (score 2):

**Implement a general "browse" feature.**

One social media-style app that impressed me with its new user experience is an app called Yonder. It's a photo sharing platform focused on outdoor adventure.

I, being a brand new user, obviously was not following anyone on this new platform, but instead of presenting me with an empty feed, it defaulted my experience to browsing the "popular" feed (which, oddly enough, it mixes in a fair amount of pictures from not-popular accounts). I'm still not following anyone on the platform, but regularly do check in to see the popular feed.

I'm not sure how exactly this could apply to your product (if users can share "posts", show the most popular, or new users in your area, etc.), but perhaps there's benefit in allowing your users to browse the general population, even if they may not be exactly the people for which your users are looking.